Consultar subcolecciones firebase cloud
soy nuevo en esto y tengo un problema al hacer consultas en firebase, creando la siguiente base de datos con subcolecciones anidadas:
    val usuarioId = usuario.correoUsuario

    val usuariosCollectionRef = db.collection("usuarios")

    val usuarioDocumentRef = usuariosCollectionRef.document(usuarioId)

    val subColeccionRef = usuarioDocumentRef.collection("instalaciones")

Se crea sin problemas pero cuando hago la consulta para que me muestre todos los documentos de instalaciones no encuentra nada
    val usuariosCollectionRef = db.collection("usuarios")

    val usuarioDocumentRef = usuariosCollectionRef.document(usuario.correoUsuario)

    val instalacionSubColeccionRef = usuarioDocumentRef.collection("instalaciones")


    instalacionSubColeccionRef.get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->

            if (result.isEmpty) {
                Log.d(TAG, "No se encontraron instalaciones")

            }

            for (document in result) {

               
                val item = document.toObject(Instalaciones::class.java)
                
              
                Log.d(TAG, "Objeto: ${document.data} ")

     
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", exception)

        }

He probado el resto del código y si es capaz de listarme la colección usuarios por lo tanto doy por hecho que el problema lo tengo en la consulta o quizás en las reglas pero no sé como configurarlas y la tengo por defecto.
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
// This rule allows anyone with your Firestore database reference to view, edit,
// and delete all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting
// started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it
// leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client
// requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
//
// Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
// all client requests to your Firestore database will be denied until you Update
// your rules
match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2024, 4, 15);
}

}
}
Gracias de antemano.
